# Exporting selected tags *with* its hierarchy

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to export some tags **with** all its sub tags?
Filtering the `@errands` tag in the agenda todo view lists all of `@errands` sub tag as expected (i.e.: bank and groceries). Why doesn't `SELECT_TAGS` do the same on exporting? I did searched and tried other options to no avail.

In the *minimal working example* bellow, only the content tagged `@errands` is exported (using LaTeX). I would expect all the sub-tags to be exported also. In this example, the content tagged `:bank:` does not get exported as expected.

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+TAGS: [ @errands : bank groceries ]
#+SELECT_TAGS: @errands

* General errands                              :@errands:
** TODO Buy matches

* Bank stuff                                       :bank:
** TODO Do pay stuff

* TODO Some other task                         :OtherTag:
```

'Any hints on how to achieve hierarchal exporting of tags?
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I imagine that the two facilities were implemented separately and hierarchical tags were not considered while writing the exporter. But for a definitive outcome, you probably should ask on the org-mode mailing list. If it is not possible, you can propose it as an encancement, but you might get suggestions about how to simulate something like this.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I will try the mailing list if my research or this thread does not turn up fruitful.

Comment: For the record, this has been implemented and should be available from the weekly ELPA archive (although there was a report that orgmode was not being built in ELPA - hopefully, just a temporary setback. It *should* be available using git, in the maint branch). See [this message from Nicolas Goaziou on the ML](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-02/msg00065.html).